# Krishna on choosing between character and a secure future?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavad-gita

I was going through this video [link](http://www.hotstar.com/tv/mahabharat/on-choosing-between-character-and-a-future/1000047914)<sup>$</sup> where god Krishna explains why one should focus on building his character rather than future. Is this mentioned anywhere in the Bhagavad Geeta?

<sup>$</sup> For those who can't watch the video, here's what Krishna says in the video:

> All parents wish to fulfill every wish of their children and keep them happy - this is the first duty of every parent. And which parent doesn't want to plan and secure their kids' future? But isn't kids' future (happiness or safety) already decided based on their past actions? So isn't what's taught (good or bad) to kids by their parents go on to determine most of their future actions (karma)? So shouldn't parents worry more about building the character of children than planning their future? But aren't most people lost in planning in their future than their character which ultimately determines their future? Think about it.

Comment: If you feel this is true than child's character is also pre-writen. For instance story of Jay and Vijay who were supposed to oppose Rama and Krishna and other Vishnu avatars in their afterlives.

Answer (score 5):

No, Krishna doesn't give any parenting advice in the Bhagavad Gita, which you can read [here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg).  The Starplus Mahabharat TV serial just has various segments where Krishna addresses the audience and gives practical advice.  They aren't meant to be quotes from scripture.

(This isn't really a proper answer, but as discussed [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/612/36) there isn't really scope for such a comprehensive answer when the answer is no.)